# Watson Assistant Launch Tool

Tags: ibm-watson

After I click on Launch tool, new blank page opens, and I cannot proceed with service creation.

Location: US South
Org: my email
Space: dev
Plan: Lite

How to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I changed location to US East, the page loaded properly.